# Prevent direct access to subfolder, redirect instead

Tags: html, apache, .htaccess, redirect

The structure looks like this:

```
html
->index.html
->subfolder
--->1.html
--->2.html
```

I want to prevent direct access when someone visits mysite.com/subfolder. The user should instead be directly redirected to the index.html on the parent folder.

How is this possible with .htaccess?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an htaccess file in the **subfolder** and add the following :

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^$ /index.html [L,R]
```

Remove the **R** flag if want to internally redirect (without changing the url) **/subfolder** to **/index.html** .

Comment: That did the trick. Thanks alot! I have a followup question. Which way would you prefer the redirect. Doing it with .htaccess or with a index.html file on each subfolder with this line of code <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url=mydomain.com" />

Comment: @Dreni htaccess redirect is better then the meta. And its faster as the server immedeatly issues redirect to the client.

Comment: Too late to edit the last comment. You can read this  [which-is-better-meta-refresh-url-redirect-or-htaccess-301-redirect](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10601881/which-is-better-meta-refresh-url-redirect-or-htaccess-301-redirect)

Answer (score 0):

Is this working out for you?

```
RewriteRule ^/subfolder/?$ http://yourdomain.com/index.html [R=301,L]
```